# How to have booth ZORDER and VORDER on a single table

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake, microsoft-fabric

I have a table called Human and I want to apply optimization technique of Zorder on Region and Area with VORDER on the whole table.

Can anyone suggest a sample code or explain what is Predator as per the documentation

```sql
OPTIMIZE <table|fileOrFolderPath> WHERE predicate 
   [ZORDER BY (col_name1, col_name2, ...)];

OPTIMIZE <table|fileOrFolderPath> WHERE predicate 
   [ZORDER BY (col_name1, col_name2, ...)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-engineering/delta-optimization-and-v-order?tabs=sparksql#control-v-order-when-optimizing-a-table), you'll see the following option:

```sql
OPTIMIZE <table|fileOrFolderPath> WHERE <predicate> 
  [ZORDER  BY (col_name1, col_name2, ...)] VORDER;
```

But if you have VOrder set as a table property or as a session flag (see linked docs), then it will be also used if you omit it when doing `OPTIMIZE`.